# OneNote on my Windows Phone 8 "can't sync"

Tags: sync, onenote

OneNote was working and synchronising but then stopped. I may have reorganised some files on my OneDrive and now OneNote is stuck. It says "can't sync" and there's no error or detail to help me.

Answer (score 6):

Resetting Office fixed it for me:

1. On your Windows Phone, Go to Settings, tap Applications, and then tap Office
2. Tap Reset Office.

Reference: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/skydrive/fix-windows-phone-docs-problem

Answer (score 3):

In Desktop OneNote, click the drop down of your note filename on the top left and you'll see a list of notebooks.

Right-click the notebook and click Notebook Sync Status...

In the next dialogue, you'll see the OneDrive path to the file. Open it and remember where it is.

Now open the Office phone app and allow time for it to refresh your OneDrive files. Then, browse to the location above and open the notebook.

This will cause the OneNote phone app to update and all should be well again (for a while ;))

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new top-level notebook via desktop OneNote (2013, Windows Store App or maybe 2010 versions)....
The OneNote Notebook files are stored in OneDrive - for me at different places.

Start OneNote 2013 - create new root Notebook, add sample page. 
Note: OneNote 2013 not default OneNote app. Windows 10 latest (no Creators installed yet).

Creates in OneDrive Documents folder - default location, can change if some other.

Then all other notebooks will start sync'ing again.  Windows Phone 1520.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall and reinstall [OneDrive app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/onedrive/9wzdncrfj1p3) on your phone.

I had the same problem and solved by reinstalling OneDrive . I think that the reason was the password change I did recently